# Get Cors Policy error in Place Autocomplete Address api by google

Tags: reactjs, google-api

Getting Error in api of auto complete place address by google.I apply this api in reactjs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are facing `CORS` which is pretty common in any API call on the web there are so many great explanations from others, here is one from StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/7232312

And this is another one on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS